# jquery + checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Сразу оворю сегодня день начался по ходу вообще не просто не с той ноги, а даже не с того дня. :)

Есть форма, в ней чекбоксы.

```
<div class="size">
<span>16.0</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="16.0" name="sizes">
</div>
<div class="size">
<span>17.0</span>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="17.0" name="sizes">
</div>
```

div size это блок в котором написан размер. При клике на него, класс меняется на **size_active** чтобы визуально было видно что выделили, самого чекбокса мы не показываем вообще

```
$(".size").click (function () {
    $(this).removeClass("size");
    $(this).addClass("size_active");
    $(this).find(":checkbox").attr("checked", "checked");
});
```

Далее, если нам этот чекбокс не нужен или нечаянно нажали, то нужно вернуть класс обратно и удалить атрибут checked. написал по тупому, но не реагирует, скорее всего я что-то упустил из-за того, что встал не с той ноги.

```
$(".size_active").click (function () {
    $(this).removeClass("size_active");
    $(this).addClass("size");
    $(this).find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
});
```

все описано в

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

задача простая, туплю дико, либо пора на пенсию, либо нужен отдых.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы просто не сделать:

```
$(this).toggleClass('size_active size')
```

Comment: спасибо, я же писал туплю.. :)